# How to convert Flux<Entity> to List<Mono<Entity>>

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I actually have a List and I need to make a request for each one.

I need to wait for all the requests for the given list to complete.

If I create a `Flux.fromIterable(entities)` and then `.flatMap(this::makeRequest)` then I'm left with a `Flux<Mono<ReturnType>>`

One thing I've done already is `Mono.when(entities.stream().map(this::makeRequest).collect(Collectors.toList()).block()`

But I'm not sure if this is the best way, or if there's a way I can use `Mono.zip` or `Flux.fromIterable`. Any help finding the best way to do this would be great.

Comment: `makeRequest` returns a `Mono<ReturnType>`. And what I really want is to wait for all of those Monos to complete before continuing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create a List. You can do the following:

```java
Flux.fromIterable(entities)
    .flatMap(this::makeRequest) // perform request for each entry
    .then() //resulting in a Mono<Void> after all requests are completed
```

You can also use `.collectList()` instead of `then` if you want to list the responses.